# typescript - Includes types in paths, but not compile them

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I got an issue in typescript. I have the following hierarchy :

```
.
+-- @types
|   +-- declaration1.ts
|   +-- declaration2.ts
+-- common
|   +-- utils1.ts
|   +-- utils2.ts
+-- tests
|   +-- utils1.test.ts
|   +-- utils2.test.ts
```

In my tsconfig.json, i put this configuration to have all my types exposed in both tests and commons (or vscode complains) :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/",
  },
  "include": ["tests", "common", "@types"]
}
```

My problem is, that i don't want to compile all this stuffs, i just want to compile the commons (which are utils, i cannot get a single (or even multiple) entrypoint(s)).

So i'd like to type `tsc` and get a `build` folder fill like this :

```
.
+-- build
|   +-- common
|   |   +-- utils1.js
|   |   +-- utils2.js
// nothing else
```

Instead i got this :

```
.
+-- build
|   +-- @types
|   |   +-- declaration1.js
|   |   +-- declaration2.js
|   +-- common
|   |   +-- utils1.js
|   |   +-- utils2.js
|   +-- tests
|   |   +-- utils1.test.js
|   |   +-- utils2.test.js
```

I cannot get how to exclude this directories from compiles.

Thanks if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating new tsconfig.json under the folder you don't want to build and add below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.ts"]     // files you want to build
}
```

and include files you want to build in original tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]     // files you want to build
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To include types but not compile them, add them to `"typeRoots"` in your `tsconfig.json`. Everything in `"include"` will be compiled.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [ "@types", "tests" ]
  }
}
```

To ignore files or directories use the `"exclude"` option, for example:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If i do so i got the error `Cannot find type definition file for 'common'.`.
VSCode also complain for not found types

Comment: You can use modules to import classes in your common files. In your `declaration.ts`: `export class Declaration { … }`. In your `utils.ts`: `import * as Declaration1 from '../@types/declaration1`. You can now use `Declaration1.Declaration` to access your class/type. There is also no need to include `typeRoots` in your `tsconfig.json` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new tsconfig.json under the folders you don't want to build, add 'noEmit: true' in it.