# IDE recognizes types but compiler does not

Tags: typescript, express-session

I am trying to convert my js code to ts code, one part is the extending an "express-session" interface to add custom properties to an interface.
I have defined a types.d.ts file for my global types, in it i have the following:

*types.d.ts*

```
declare module 'express-session' {
  export interface CustomSessionData {
    user?: User_t;    
  }
  interface SessionData extends CustomSessionData {}
}
export = {};
```

My IDE and Compiler are fine with importing *CustomSessionData* and *SessionData* interfaces where they are being used:

*middleware.ts*

```
import { CustomSessionData } from 'express-session';

export default function useSession(
  fn: (
    session: Session,
    setSession: (new_session: CustomSessionData | undefined) => void
  ) => void
) {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void) => {
    const session: Session = req.session;
    const setSession = (new_data: CustomSessionData | undefined) => {
      req.session = { ...session, ...new_data } as Session;
    };

    fn(session, setSession);

    next();
  };
}
```

However when i then try to use the *useSession* function, and mutate the session.user property, the IDE accepts this, giving autocomplete, but the compiler throws an error, claiming "Property 'user' does not exist on type 'SessionData'. Note *SessionData* extends *CustomSessionData* so the property should exist.

I dont understand why the compiler wont recognize this but the IDE does, so help in finding out why would be appreciated.

I am compiling with ts-node.

*tsconfig*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020" 
    "module": "CommonJS"
    "moduleResolution": "node"
    "allowJs": true
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    "esModuleInterop": true                          
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true     
    "strict": true    
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./build/**/*"],
  "include": ["./**/*.ts", "types"]
}
```

*types.d.ts* is in the included *types/* folder

I have tried changing my tsconfig to add:

```
"include": ["types"]
```

I have also tried using following:

- [How To Get Typescript Compiler To See My Global Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74513147/how-to-get-typescript-compiler-to-see-my-global-types/74513156#74513156)
- [typescript - Includes types in paths, but not compile them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145331/typescript-includes-types-in-paths-but-not-compile-them)
- [Global types in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984889/global-types-in-typescript)

Apologies for the large code snippets with limited context, i have been trying to fix this on and off for the last week and don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with ts-node.
The solution required adding *"files":true* to ts-node in tsconfig as follows:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "compilerOptions":{
    //...
  }
```

I am not sure why this worked, but it did.

Taken from:
[ts-node ignores d.ts files while tsc successfully compiles the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610583/ts-node-ignores-d-ts-files-while-tsc-successfully-compiles-the-project)